# Script is getting opened in ms script host

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line-interface

I am trying to create a cli with node, and I have the following key in `package.json`

```json
  "bin": {
    "ping":"index.js"
  },
```

and my `index.js` file

```js
console.log("Pong! Yeah");
```

But this is getting opened in **microsoft script-host**, and not in node.. How to fix it?

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zamiS.png)

Comment: How are you trying to run it?

Comment: @Barmar i first install it using `npm i -g`, then try using the command (`ping`)

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to add this line!

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
```